# $\lim_{ x\to 0^+}f(x)=?$

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, and for all $0\le x\le\frac{1}{a}$ satisfis $f(ax)=bf(x)$. ($a,b>1$)

$\lim_{ x\to 0^+}f(x)=?$

Comment: try substituting $x=\frac{h}{a}$. might be of help

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = f(\tfrac{1}{a^n})$. Then your equation tells you $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{b}$. Because $a_0 = f(1)$ you get $a_n = \tfrac{f(1)}{b^n}$. Since $b>1$ you get $a_n \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

---

Okay, one has to show that the limit exists, so here is a full argument in the same spirit:

Let $x ∈ [0..1]$. Arguing just as above, you also get $f(\tfrac{x}{a^n}) = \tfrac{f(x)}{b^n}$. And so $\lvert f(\tfrac{x}{a^n})\rvert ≤ \tfrac{C}{b^n}$ where $C > 0$ bounds $f$.

Now, for any $ε > 0$ take $N ∈ ℕ$ large enough so that $\tfrac{C}{b^N} < ε$. Then take $δ = \tfrac{1}{a^N}$. Now you can write any $y ∈ [0..δ)$ as $y = \tfrac{x}{a^N}$ for some $x ∈ [0..1)$ and, by the above, $\lvert f(y) \rvert ≤\tfrac{C}{b^N} < ε$.

This shows $f(x) \overset{x → 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Comment: In addition to this, one would need to show that the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is bounded, let $|f(x) | < M $.

For any $\epsilon$, let $ n$ be the largest integer such that $ a^{n} \epsilon \leq 1 < a^{n+1}\epsilon $. What can we say about $|f(\epsilon) |$?

**Hint:** Apply the condition in the question $n$ times.

Hence, determine the value of $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$